# How to go to tab 5 in Safari? (AppleScript)

Tags: safari, applescript

Is there any way to go to tab number 5 in Safari?

```
tell application "Safari" to set current tab of document 1 to 5
```

Answer (score 3):

This maybe an old question but I ran into this same problem.   The solutions so far don't seem to work with Safari 7.x.   This is what I had to do

```
tell front window of application "Safari"
    set current tab to tab gmailTabindex
end tell
```

The key is the "front window of".  If you don't have that it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 5
```

If you run `tell app "Safari" to properties of window 1`, you'll see that `current tab` is a property of windows, and that the class of its value is `tab`.